# How to configure Ebean to generate SQLite code

Tags: java, sqlite, ebean

I am using Play Framework 2.3.4 with Ebean and I am trying to use SQLite to persist the data on my application. When I try to run the application, I get this error:

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table address already exists)
[ERROR:1, SQLSTATE:null], while trying to run this SQL script:

...
alter table book add constraint fk_book_publisher_1 foreign key (publisher_name) references publisher (name);
...
```

After searching a while, I found out that SQLite does not allow the addition of a foreign key after the table is created. So, is there anyway to specify Ebean to generate SQLite code?

Comment: It looks like this known issue: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/100

Comment: Thank you, Rob. As I was in the beginning of my project, I decided to go ahead with MySQL instead of SQLite. It would be a nice fix, though.